# Boost up bulk Groovy eval() with caching

Tags: groovy

i am writing a program for bulk processing excel files. each row's data is put into a map and the filename and the sheetname determines the script that processed the fetched data. these scripts are not bundled into my program, they are not even classes implementing a specific interface.

this is the processing loop logic:

```
excelfile.eachLineOnSheet { line, sheet ->
  def data = extractData();
  def lineprocessorscript = determineLineProcessor(excelfile, sheet);

  Eval.xy data, outputfile, lineprocessorscript

}
```

Of course this is easy, but on large files i'd like to improve performance. first i cached lineprocessors' code, so that .groovy files are read only once.

is it possible to make Eval.xy faster by caching the compiled script somehow?
i'd like to keep my scripts simple, so that the do not implement any interface or stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Binil Thomas answer helped me to start. I looked at the Groovy sources and saw that `GroovyClassLoader` has a built-in caching, but when called from `Eval` direction the caching is turned off:

```
private Class parseClass(final GroovyCodeSource codeSource) throws CompilationFailedException {
  // Don't cache scripts
  return loader.parseClass(codeSource, false);
}
```

Why not cache scripts..? This is exactly what I needed.. :-) So I wrote the stuff that Eval does based on the sources and this came out:

```
lineprocessors.each {

  if(cachedLineProcessorCodes[it] == null) {
    def gsc = new GroovyCodeSource(new File(it).getText(), it, 'DEFAULT_CODE_BASE')
    Class cc = gcl.parseClass(gsc, true)
    cachedLineProcessorCodes[it] = cc
  }

  def binding = new Binding()
  binding.setVariable("x", linedata)
  binding.setVariable("y", lineProcFiles[it])

  def Script sc = InvokerHelper.createScript(cachedLineProcessorCodes[it], binding)
  sc.run()

  //Eval.xy linedata, lineProcFiles[it], new File(it).getText()

}
```

In my case, when 7900 lines were processed by the groovy script, the runtime decreased from ~73s to ~5s.

Comment: that is awesome improvement! Although you do not like the script to implement any particular interface, I would recommend renaming the bound variables, now that you have the opportunity, to something more meaningful than `x` and `y`. This will help the maintenance of the script files in future, IMHO.

Comment: thank you, i did that in real, just not posted this change here, to keep the commented Eval.xy line and the new solution 100% compatible :-)

Answer (score 3):

my take on it

```
deg gcl = ... // probably new GroovyClassLoader(this.class.classLoader)
def cache = [:].withDefault{gcl.parseClass(new File(it))}
...
lineprocessors.each {
  cache[it].newInstance([someVariable:1, otherVariable:2] as Binding).run()
}
```

a couple of comments regarding your own answer
you don't really need to create the gsc yourself, just load the file with the gcl.
if you are dealing with scripts, you don't really need the `InvokerHelper`, you can instantiate them yourself.
take advantage of groovy syntax =D

Comment: I didn't know these features, but they are really impressive. learnt a lot from your answer too, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`Eval.xy`](http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/util/Eval.java) invokes [`GroovyShell.evaluate`](http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.java) method. The various forms of `GroovyShell.evaluate` all boils down to this form:

```
public Object evaluate(GroovyCodeSource codeSource) 
        throws CompilationFailedException {
    Script script = parse(codeSource);
    script.setBinding(context);
    return script.run();
}
```

I have not tried this out yet, but you might be able to reuse the `Script` object by invoking it with different bindings for each line in your XLS sheet.

Comment: +1: thank you, your answer helped me to get the desired result, that I posted in a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use MVEL for such tasks which much faster by tests http://mvel.codehaus.org/Performance+of+MVEL+2.0 and not more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

You should preparse your Script, thats typically the most intense part:

```
String code = '$obj.toString()'
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
Script script = shell.parse(code, 'preparsed')
items.each {item ->
  sh.setVariable('$obj', item)
  Object result = s.run()
}
```